# Как сделать сохранение логина отдельной кнопкой на форме через JS?

Tags: javascript

Проблема такая, клиент не хочет запоминать логин и пароль в браузере, хочет заходить каждый раз сам, но и логин повторно вводить каждый раз не хочет. Я добавил на форму кнопку сохранения пароля, по её нажатию логин должен сохранится в куки(?) и при следующем заходе подставлять логин автоматически. В js не силен, как взять значение из поля логина понимаю, а как/куда сохранять и как/откуда его потом брать не знаю. Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой или есть готовые решения? 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eсли только логин, то в `localStorage` можно сохранить, при заходе на сайт проверяйте его на `null`, если он не `null`, то подставляйте.

Как-то так:

```
initLogin(){ //при заходе на страницу
  loginInput.value = localStorage.getItem('savedLogin') || ''; //loginInput это html input
}

login(){ //обработчик входа
 localStorage.saveItem('savedLogin', loginInput.value);
}
```

Однако стоит помнить, что данные будут хранится долгое время и в открытом виде, но насколько я понимаю, задача именно в этом.

Comment: Как вариант, можно в md5 (или что-то подобное) зашифровать, а на сайте провести все в обратную сторону.

Comment: из md5 в текст?

Comment: При записи в localStorage записать в md5, а при добавлении логина в текстовое поле обратно преобразовать в текст

Comment: Ну md5 сделан для того, чтобы нельзя было из хэша восстановить исходный текст, сейчас есть конечно онлайн сервисы, но они просто ищут такой же хэш в базе соответствий. Можно конечно на серверной части хранить хэш и отправлять его вместо логина, так даже лучше, если соединение не защищено, но факт остаётся фактом, информация будет в открытом виде, хоть и не понятно будет, какой изначально был логин.

Comment: @Komdosh а если через чек бокс? типа когда он включен чтоб запоминалось

Comment: ну добавьте проверку на чекбокс, в чём проблема